# Maven deploy non jar file on to nexus repository using bamboo

Tags: java, maven, deployment, bamboo, continuous-deployment

I want to deploy my build file (format *.cba) to nexus repository using Bamboo. This build file was generated by ANT. I am using maven deploy command without pom file as bamboo task within a stage. Command below.

The build file `*.cba` is a shared artifact.

```
-X deploy:deploy-file 
-Dfile=${bamboo.artifacts.path.buildFile}
-Dpackaging=cba
-Durl=https://nexus.internal.organisation.com/content/repositories/snapshots/
-DrepositoryId=snapshots
-DgroupId=com.organisation.art
-DartifactId=myproject
-Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

When bamboo runs this command, I am always getting this error.

> [INFO] Downloading: https://nexus.internal.organisation.com/content/repositories/art-snapshots/com/organisation/art/myproject/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>   [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.organisation.art:myproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to art-snapshots (https://nexus.internal.organisation.com/content/repositories/art-snapshots/): /home/art/username/work/SILF/.m2/repository/com/organisation/art/myproject/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-art-snapshots.xml.part.lock (No such file or directory)
>   org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata com.organisation.art:myproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to art-snapshots (https://nexus.internal.organisation.com/content/repositories/art-snapshots/): /home/art/username/work/SILF/.m2/repository/com/organisation/art/myproject/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-art-snapshots.xml.part.lock (No such file or directory)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.MetadataTransportListener.transferFailed(MetadataTransportListener.java:43)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:222)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.upload(DefaultDeployer.java:417)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:290)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
>       at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute(DeployFileMojo.java:310)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/art/username/work/SILF/.m2/repository/com/organisation/art/myproject/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-art-snapshots.xml.part.lock (No such file or directory)
>       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
>       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.PartialFile$LockFile.tryLock(PartialFile.java:123)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.PartialFile$LockFile.lock(PartialFile.java:71)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.PartialFile$LockFile.(PartialFile.java:58)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.PartialFile$Factory.newInstance(PartialFile.java:210)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:432)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
>       ... 32 more

I am thinking there is some problem with the versioning. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue using the below command. Hope this will help.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file 
-Dfile=${bamboo.artifacts.path.cbaFile} 
-Dpackaging=cba 
-DgeneratePom=false 
-DupdateReleaseInfo=true 
-Durl=https://nexus.organisation.com/content/repositories/snapshots  
-DrepositoryId=snapshots  
-DgroupId=com.organisation.dept 
-DartifactId=myproject 
-Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 0):

`cba` is AFAIK not a valid packaging value, see "packaging":

https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Maybe you are better off by zipping your script and deploy it with packaging "zip".

Comment: Hey JF, eventhough cba is not a valid packaging, maven deploy plugin allowed me to deploy. I have answered my question below

Comment: @Vikram Ok, but I wouldn't be surprised if some mechanisms of your Nexus/Artifactory do not work as expected.